Flask-Form is not validating my submission, render_kv={"disabled":""}
I try to submit my form, but I think it does not validated, because it's not saving the post and redirecting and so on
<form method="POST" class="form shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-body-tertiary rounded">
        
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}
        
        {{form.title.label(class="form-label")}}
        {{form.title(class="form-control", placeholder="My Awesome Title")}}

        {{form.content.label(class="form-label")}}
        {{form.content(class="form-control", rows="5")}} 

        {{form.author.label(class="form-label")}}
        {{form.author(class="form-control", value=current_user.username)}}

        {{form.slug.label(class="form-label")}}
        {{form.slug(class="form-control", placeholder="my_awesome_title")}}

        {{form.submit(class="btn btn-info mt-3")}}
    </form>


Here is my PostForm class
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField("Title", validators=[DataRequired()])
    content = StringField("Content", validators=[DataRequired()], widget=TextArea())
    author = StringField("Author", validators=[DataRequired()], render_kw={'disabled':''})
    slug = StringField("Slug", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label="Submit!")

There might be a problem due to the author's value... Just an assumption.
Thanks to anybody that can help
I was trying to add author's new, same as the current_user.username, I don't want someone to manipulate it. After some updates, couldn't validate the form.

Got the solution.
Problem was:
render_kw={'disabled':''}

Changed it to:
render_kw={'readonly':''}

Same functionality, but it worked!
